# Is there any settings in wpf to align buttons in fixed distance

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

App contain more than 30 buttons but there alignments are incorrect 
my question is: 
Is there any property for arranging all 30 button in fixed length and height?

Comment: Do you mean designer operation? Like selecting them all and then entering size which applies to all of them?

Comment: Have you tried a `Grid` or `UniformGrid` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want share same setting between all 30 buttons you should use [`Styles`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="20" />
</Style>
```

After you'll have all buttons with width 20. This is happening due to a concept called [implicit styles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2009/08/27/implicit-styles-templates-controls-and-frameworkelements.aspx). Any time you are specifying style without *Key* it will automatically apply it to all `TargetTypes` without explicitly defined style.

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using a [`Style`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.style(v=vs.110).aspx) to declare your `Button` dimensions? Try adding this into your `Resources` section:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="24" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

This will affect *all* `Button`s within scope of the `Style`, but you could change it to this...:

```
<Style x:Key="SizedButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="24" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="150" />
</Style>
```

... and then explicitly assign the `Style` to each `Button`:

```
<Button Content="Something" Style="{StaticResource SizedButton}" />
```